# Is it possible to impose a type constraint on List<Interface>?

Tags: c#, .net

In My class I have

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{

//I want MyClass only to be able to accept object of type List<SomethingElse>
public List<ISomething> ListOfSomethings {get; set;}

}

interface IMyInterface{

List<ISomething> ListOfSomethings {get; set;}

}

class SomethingElse : ISomething{

}

class SomethingMore : Isomething{

}
```

Basically I want to know if it is possible to constrain the type that the list uses in MyClass, so if someone tried coding it to the wrong type (i.e. a List of SomethingMore) it would throw an exception.

EDIT: If this is not possible to do, is there an alternative solution that would work?

Answer (score 5):

You can constrain the `T` (type) of the list items (and any other `T`) by using the `where` restriction:

for more details see [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

**Interfaces**:

```
interface ISomething { }
```

Allows to only use `T`s that implement the interface `ISomething`.

```
interface IMyInterface<T> where T : ISomething
{
    List<T> ListOfSomethings { get; set; }
}
```

**Classes**:

```
class SomethingElse : ISomething { }

class SomethingMore : ISomething { }

class MyClass1 : IMyInterface<SomethingElse>
{
    public List<SomethingElse> ListOfSomethings { get; set; }
}

class MyClass2 : IMyInterface<SomethingMore>
{
    public List<SomethingMore> ListOfSomethings { get; set; }
}
```

You can restrict the `T` whereever it suits you. Here for example on the class itself.
This allows only `SomethingElse`

```
class MyClass3<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : SomethingElse
{
    public List<T> ListOfSomethings { get; set; }
}
```

an example with a `Dictionary`:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, IMyInterface<ISomething>>();
dic.Add("MyClass1", (IMyInterface<ISomething>)new MyClass1());
dic.Add("MyClass2", (IMyInterface<ISomething>)new MyClass2());
```

if you won't cast it everytime then the only solution that I can currently think of is to create your custom dictionary and encapsulate the casting:

```
class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, IMyInterface<ISomething>>
{
    public void Add(string key, MyClass1 value)
    {
        base.Add(key, (IMyInterface<ISomething>)value);
    }

    public void Add(string key, MyClass2 value)
    {
        base.Add(key, (IMyInterface<ISomething>)value);
    }
}

var dic2 = new MyDictionary();
dic2.Add("MyClass1", new MyClass1());
dic2.Add("MyClass2", new MyClass2());
```

Comment: Everywhere I have MyClass in my program I have to add the <SomethingElse>, is that correct?

Comment: @t3chb0t I have a problem I'm not sure how to fix.  I defined a Dictionary as <string, IMyInterface>  but now I must change to <string, IMyInterface<ISomething>>.  With that I get an error about cannot convert from interface type to the concrete type when I try to add <string, MyClass> to the dictionary.

Comment: @erotavlas I'm afraid you'll need to cast it. I've added an example with a dictionary.

Comment: @t3chb0t thanks, is there any way to work with the interface types - without specifying the concrete type of <T> (just the interface) even though I added them to the dictionary with a specific type <T>

Comment: @erotavlas I've edited my answer and added another example. I don't know anyother way to do it and it think it might be impossible yet. You can however hide it by creating your own `Add` methods on your custom dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
//I want MyClass only to be able to accept object of type List<SomethingElse>
```

Then you can't define it as `List<ISomething>`, but rather use a different interface or even a concrete type. If you define it as `List<ISomething>`, than it automatically accepts anything, that implements `ISomething` interface. There's no way around that.

Comment: If you downvote, please state the reason as well, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`C#` is a typesafe by language design, so there is no way the consumer of your list can inject into it a type which is not `SomethingElse`  or `SomethingMore`.

If you need to constrain to some of types derived from common interface, like `SomethingElse`, I would go

1. Hide a property that exposes a `List` itself

   ```
   private List<ISomething> ListOfSomethings {get; set;}
   ```
2. Add a public member function, say `FromList`

   ```
   public void FromList(List<SomethingElse> somethings)
   {
       ListOfSomethings = somethings;
   }
   ```

This function becomes the only way to assign a list to a class, and considering that it accepts only lists of certain type, you are created desired limitation.

Comment: I get an error when I try this method.  Cannot implicitly convert type List<SomethingElse> to List<ISomething>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using **[explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)**:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    List<ISomething> IMyInterface.ListOfSomethings
    {
        get { return this.ListOfSomethings.Cast<ISomething>().ToList(); }
        set { this.ListOfSomethings = value.Cast<SomethingMore>().ToList(); }
    }

    List<SomethingMore> ListOfSomethings { get; set; } 
}
```

Please note that it is not recommended to make such a restriction, because this violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): The user of your class might be using the IMyInterface interface and has no idea that its type is restricted.

Another problem is exposing a `List<T>` like this in an interface: The caller can either call list methods like Add or Remove or set the entire List instance. This is probably not what you want. If you want to expose a readonly collection, use a getter with an array or enumerable type.

Comment: That is a good note, it makes me question if doing this is a good idea

Comment: No, it's not. But you asked if it's possible, and it is possible. If you can avoid it, use type constraints as suggested by t3chb0t.